# Admin-ajax.php 400 error in custom theme

Tags: ajax

It seems that this is a common issue. I have googled and searched Stack Exchange about this but didn't find any solution that helps in my situation.

**Problem: When trying to use Ajax with admin-ajax.php, I always get the error 400.**

```
POST https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm building a web site for my client with my custom made theme. I created custom post type with custom post status 'Archived'. I'm trying to add a new column with a button in the custom post listing. With this button the admin can set the custom post as archived with single click.

Here is the simplified version of the code. I removed unrelated codes here.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_post_archived', 'set_post_archived' );
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'set_post_archived_js' );

function set_post_archived_js() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.set-archived-button').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                var data  = {
                    action: 'set_post_archived',
                    post_id: $(this).data('post_id'),   
                };
                
                jQuery.post(
                    ajaxurl, data,
                    function(response) {
                    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function set_post_archived()
{
  // The function code here...
  
  wp_die();
}
```

The button's code is

```
<a href="#" data-post_id="70" class="button set-archived-button">Archive</a>
```

Post id in `data-post_id` is created dynamically.

As mentioned, this code is on the backend, so `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action_hook}` shouldn't be required.

**Background-info**

I have tried both `jQuery.post()` and `jQuery.ajax()`. Seems that, it doesn't make difference.
Here is how the code is being loaded if it matters.

In `functions.php`:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    // Only if on backend
    require get_template_directory() . '/admin/admin-functions.php';
}
```

In `/admin/admin-functions.php`:

```
global $pagenow;
if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' || $pagenow == 'post.php' ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/admin/machines-functions.php';
}
```

The actual code with Ajax is in the file `/admin/machines-functions.php`.

Comment: I suspect this is caused by a common mistake, however, this mistake ssimply does not happen if you had used a REST API endpoint for your AJAX rather than the old `admin-ajax.php` api, and if something had happened it would have given you a plaintext error message in human readable language. Is there a specific reason you decided to use the older API? In fact on closer inspection of your Q I suspect what you want can be done with a request to the WP Core official endpoints that already exist!

Comment: No specific reason why I'm using admin-ajax.php. This is all new to me, so I'm learning all this right now and REST API is surely something I will look into in the near future :) Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're adding the AJAX action only if `$pagenow` (the current admin page/file) is `edit.php` or `post.php`, and that's not going to work on `admin-ajax.php`, so you should instead add the action via the `admin_init` hook if you wish to add the action only on the admin side. E.g.

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_post_archived', 'set_post_archived' );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution. It started working partially after removing the use of $pagenow. When I moved all the codes from the different file (machines-functions.php) to main admin functions file (admin-functions.php), it started working perfectly. I believe there is a method to separate these codes in to different file which is being loaded only when the admin is on certain page(s), but I need to look into this more.

Comment: Well, good luck with that, but do consider using the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post) - it's easy once you get yourself familiar with the fundamental. :)